# PowerBI Embedded without AD using data from AAS

Tags: powerbi-embedded, azure-analysis-services, row-level-security

We have the below architecture to be built. The web application is not integrated with AD and has a its own user auth (User and Tenant mapping table). We need embed the PowerBI reports and use the app user table for RLS.

The architecture is as below. Please advise
https://ibb.co/DDWG6Rg

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** Azure Analysis Services uses Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) for identity management and user authentication. Any user creating, managing, or connecting to an Azure Analysis Services server must have a valid user identity in an Azure AD tenant in the same subscription.

[image]

For more details, refer "[Azure Analysis Services Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-manage-users)".

Power BI Embedded does support using RLS against AAS using the CUSTOMDATA() function.

For more details, refer similar ask in PowerBI forum: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Azure-Analysis-Services-RLS-and-Embedding/td-p/239127

Hope this helps.